# H2 conditional MERGE

Tags: sql, h2

Is it possible in H2 to create a `MERGE` statement which is only updates the row **IF** the condition is true or a hack like in mysql `insert into on duplicate key` something like this:

```
MERGE INTO test_table KEY(city) 
VALUES(DECODE(modification_date < '2015-11-11','foo1','foo'), 'UK', '2015-11-11');
```

The above example won't work unfortunately.

My table: city varchar(200) primary key, country_code varchar (2), modification_date date

Answer (score 0):

I just bumped into your question while trying to find a clue on something somewhat related, but it appears at least from the documentation that you can specify a condition as part of the `ON` clause in a [MERGE USING](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#merge_using) command. I haven't tested this out to see if it allows for arbitrary expressions or not but I looks to me like it has a good chance of doing what you need.